# `str.upper()` method does not respect `LC_CTYPE` setting, but `pyicu` does

Tags: python, string, unicode, locale

When using Python's own `locale` module and `str.upper()` method, `'istanbul'.upper()` returns incorrect result.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8')
>>> 'tr_TR.UTF-8'
>>> s1 = 'istanbul'
>>> s1.upper()
'ISTANBUL'
```

If I install and use `pyicu` it works as expected.

```
>>> from icu import Locale, UnicodeString
>>> tr = Locale('tr_TR.UTF-8')
>>> s2 = UnicodeString('istanbul')
>>> str(s2.toUpper(tr))
'İSTANBUL'
```

How can I make sure Python's built-in modules and methods work properly for the given locale?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately can't do it without using packages. As you have said that you can use `pyicu` but if you don't want to use it, than you can hardcode it:

```
import re

def tr_upper(word):
    word = re.sub(r"i", "İ", word)
    word = re.sub(r"ı", "I", word)
    word = re.sub(r"ç", "Ç", word)
    word = re.sub(r"ş", "Ş", word)
    word = re.sub(r"ü", "Ü", word)
    word = re.sub(r"ğ", "Ğ", word)
    word = word.upper() # for the rest use default upper
    return word

print( tr_upper("istanbul") ) #İSTANBUL
```

Comment: In the official python docs it says:
`locale.LC_CTYPE¶
Locale category for the character type functions. Depending on the settings of this category, the functions of module string dealing with case change their behaviour.`
But your answer means python does not use `LC_CTYPE` at all. I just can't believe it. Not you, the situation.

Comment: It seem that python cannot correctly handle `i, İ, I, ı` and it is a very common problem in the software world.

Comment: @kureta: it is not a problem of Python, because such things are offloaded to operating system. ICU uses a own localization database. So could you check that operating system has your locale installed (`locale -a`), with correct spelling, and that it can do such transformation?

Comment: Correction (of my previous comment). Python uses generalized Unicode algorithm. So according python doc "There is no way to perform case conversions and character classifications according to the locale", which it is shame, because they know about the problem.